# convert a dictionary into a dictionary with list of values in python using two list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list like

```
['a','b','c']
['x','y','z']
```

I want to create a dictionary which holds values as list like,

```
{'a':['x'],'b':['y'],'c':['z']}
```

I am using like this but gives me values not in list :

```
dictionary = dict(zip(out_head, (select11)))
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a list for each element in `select11`

```
dictionary = dict(zip(out_head,
                        ([x] for x in select11)
                        ))
```

Alternatively (@kpie reminds me of dict-comprehension notation):

```
dictionary = {k:[v] for k,v in zip(out_head, select11)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `list` on each element in the second list before zipping them.

```
x, y = ['a','b','c'], ['x','y','z'] 
new = dict(zip(x, [list(i) for i in y]))
print new
```

Comment: Beware, though, that `list('abc')` results in `['a', 'b', 'c']`, not `['abc']`.  This may or may not be relevant to the actual data being processed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you are looking for is this.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b','c']
d = {k:[v] for (k,v) in [(q,w) for q in a for w in b]}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > > a = ['a','b','c']
> > >       b = ['x','y','z']
> > >
> > > dict(zip(a,map(list, b)))

The map(list) wraps each member of list b in its own list, which is what you say you want.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the response

Comment: Beware, though, that `list('abc')` results in `['a', 'b', 'c']`, not `['abc']`.  This may or may not be relevant to the data being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
 keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 values = ['x', 'y', 'z']
 dictionary = dict(zip(keys, list(values)))
```